# Android disable Activity to request while changing mode (prtrait/landscape)

Tags: android, android-activity

I have Acivity which in it's onCreate method makes requset in Asynctask to remote server, takes data and renders them. It's ok, but when I'm trying to change mode to landscape - hall this process starts from the very begining and I have to wait untill data come from server one more time. I don't need it. I need just renderng the same data to landscape mode. How to do it?

Comment: Please check out the [link](http://gafurbabu.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/how-to-handle-screen-orientation-change-when-process-some-work-and-background-thread-active/) [Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) It is not same work that you want but here maintain screen orientation change. I think it help you. Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> hall this process starts from the very begining

It is happening because your activity is restarting after orientation.

So to prevent restart do following.

**Make following changes in your activity in manifest.**

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName" 
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screensize" />
```

ScreenSize attribute seems to be added in 4.0 so don't mentioned it if you are running below 4.0.

**And then add the following method to Your Activity:**

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

It will prevent your activity from restarting.